# An isomorphism of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In this thread:  [proving that a ring does not have ACCP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354777) it was stated that

$$\varphi:R\to\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{1/2},x^{1/4},\dots]$$ sending $x_n$ to $x^{2^{-n}}$  is an isomorphism, where
$$R=\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots]}{(x_1-x_2^2,x_2-x_3^2,\dots)}.$$

I got that $\varphi$ is surjective, and $ (x_1-x_2^2,x_2-x_3^2,\dots) \subseteq \ker \varphi.$ But I get stuck in another inclusion. How can I show that $\ker \varphi \subseteq (x_1-x_2^2,x_2-x_3^2,\dots)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any $f\in \mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2, \ldots]$ only uses finitely many variables, so it is enough to show that $\mathbb{Z}[x_0, \ldots , x_n] \to \mathbb{Z}[t^{1/2^n}]$ has kernel generated by $\{x_i-x_{i+1}^2\}$.

We can show this by observing that $\ker(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\to\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{1/2}]) = (x-y^2)$, and using induction.

Comment: If $f \in \ker(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]\to\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{1/2}]),$ then $f(t, t^{1/2}) = 0.$ But I don't know how to show $f \in (x -y^2).$ Sorry, I'm trying to study algebra recently.

Comment: If we replace every occurrence of $x$ in $f$ with $y^2$, we get a polynomial $g$ that depends only on $y$, such that $f-g \in (x-y^2) \subset \ker$. (to show this, consider each monomial in $f$ separately) If $f$ is in the kernel, so 
is $g$, so $g(t^{1/2})$ is identically zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.